# Discrimination and calibration of Cox model

Tags: r, predictive-models, cox-model

I have been working on fitting Cox model for prediction by using the [rms](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/index.html) package. I want to measure model calibration and discrimination.
Discrimination was measured by using `rms::validate()`; `Dxy` can be transferred to [@Frank Harrell](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/4253/frank-harrell)'s $c$ index. But in this way, I cannot get 95% CI for the $c$ index. How can I do this in R? 
And by the way, what value should be in $c$ index to present the model's well?

Calibration was done using `rms::calibrate()`, but I cannot get the calibration plot which presented concordance of predicted and observed events in Cox model. How can I do this calibration plot of Cox model in R or SAS.

Comment: Note that if you ever need to do out-of-sample (external) validation, the `rcorr.cens` function in the R `Hmisc` package provides the standard error of Somers' $D_{xy}$ which gives rise to a confidence interval that can be translated to an interval for $c$.  But for internal validation we don't at present have a standard error for $D_{xy}$.

Answer (score 3):

Using R:

```
library(rms)   
x <- cph(Surv(time, event) ~ pred 1 + pred2, x=TRUE, y=TRUE, 
         surv=TRUE, time.inc =1, dxy = TRUE, data = dataname)    
c1 <- calibrate(x, u=1)    
plot(c1)
```

Comment: It would be great if you could comment on your code, for future readers or people not used to R.